# How to fix missing default argument on parameter 'args' with clang?

Tags: c++

I have a short and convenient code for multi-dimensional vectors, with the ability to choose size and default value during initialization.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

template<int D, typename T>
struct Vec : public vector<Vec<D - 1, T>> {
    static_assert(D >= 1, "Vector dimension must be greater than zero!");
    template<typename... Args>
    Vec(int n = 0, Args... args) : vector<Vec<D - 1, T>>(n, Vec<D - 1, T>(args...)) {}
};
template<typename T>
struct Vec<1, T> : public vector<T> {
    Vec(int n = 0, const T& val = T()) : vector<T>(n, val) {}
};

int main() {
    int nbRow, nbCol;
    std::cin >> nbRow >> nbCol;
    Vec<2, int> grid(nbRow, nbCol, 0);
}
```

It works with GCC, but not with clang 10.0.0 (standard c++17 or gnu++17, both don't work).

```
main.cpp:15:25: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
        Vec(int n = 0, Args... args) : vector<Vec<D - 1, T>>(n, Vec<D - 1, T>(args...)) {}
                               ^
main.cpp:30:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Vec<2, int>::Vec<int, int>' requested here
        Vec<2, int> grid(nbRow, nbCol, 7);
                    ^
main.cpp:15:25: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
        Vec(int n = 0, Args... args) : vector<Vec<D - 1, T>>(n, Vec<D - 1, T>(args...)) {}
```

Is there a simple way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On which line? Give the error _verbatim_, not just snippets of it!

Comment: By the way, rectangular multidimensional vectors should not be implemented by nesting `std::vector`.

Comment: Line 15, added the full error, sorry. I know having a lot of small vectors is quite bad, but I still would like to make this code work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int n = 0` an argument with a default value can't be followed by arguments without defaults. Remove the `=0`

Comment: It works, thanks! I will accept your answer when the site will let me do it.